# DAX users with multiple emails

Tags: sql, dax, measure, equivalent

I have a "transaction table" with user unique username, email address and other columns. I would like to create a measure that shows unique users with unique multiple emails. should by the equivalent of this sql statement:

```
select user, count(distinct email)
from usertable
group by user
having count(distinct email) >1
```

Answer (score 1):

This DAX will return a table, equivalent to your SQL statement:

```
UsersWithMultipleEmail = 
    FILTER ( 
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( 
            usertable[user],
            "# emails", COUNTROWS ( usertable )
        ),
        [# emails] > 1
    )
```

This measure will return the number of distinct emails, which you can then use in a visualisation:

```
MultipleEmails = 
    IF (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( usertable[email] ) > 1,
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( usertable[email] ),
        BLANK()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that measures return scalars, not tabular resultsets. So I'll answer in three ways here. The first is the least DAX, and leans on filtering in client reporting tools. The second is a measure which does the filtering internally, so will always return the count of users with >1 email. And the last is a DAX query which is equivalent to the SQL query.

First, though, I'll make a quick and dirty dataset in Power BI to work with:

```
//Users
let
    Source =
        #table(
            {"User", "Email"},
            {{"Bob", "bob1@example.com"},
             {"Bob", "bob2@example.com"},
             {"Joe", "joe@example.com"},
             {"Joe", "joe@example.com"},
             {"Jane", "jane@example.com"}})
in
    Source
```

This nets us a table that looks like this:

```
User    Email
Bob     bob1@example.com
Bob     bob2@example.com
Joe     joe@example.com
Joe     joe@example.com
Jane    jane@example.com
```

So, for our simple version:

```
Distinct Emails = DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Users'[Email] )
```

And we can build a visual of 'User'[User] and [DistinctEmails] with a filter on [DistinctEmails] > 1:

[image: distinct > 1]

So now the measure that always returns the count of users with distinct count of emails > 1. This will work even in visuals not using the 'Users'[User] field, or at sub and grand total level. Note this is a user count, not an email count.

```
User Count with Multiple Distinct Emails = 
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( 'Users'[User] ),
        [Distinct Emails] > 1
    )
)
```

Note here that we're using our [Distinct Emails] in the definition of this measure. `FILTER` iterates the table passed in arg1. This is `VALUES ( 'Users'[User] )`, which returns a 1-column table of unique values in the column. For each row in that table, it evaluates the predicate in arg2, `[Distinct Emails] > 1`. So it removes any users failing that test. `FILTER` outputs the table of all values that passed the test. `COUNTROWS` ... well it counts the rows. q:

Here's that measure on a visual. Note that there are no filters on the visual.
[image: users with multiple emails]

And finally an equivalent query to your original SQL.

```
EVALUATE
FILTER (
  SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Users'[User],
    "Email Count", [Distinct Emails]
  ),
  [Email Count] > 1
)
```

`SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` selects, groups, filters, and projects. Here we're using it to select and group 'Users'[User]. We're projecting a new column, aliased "Email Count" with the calculation [Distinct Emails] (the measure we defined above). We pass the output of `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` (a two-column table of 'Users'[User] and [Email Count]) into `FILTER` which checks the value of the projected column, [Email Count].

Resultset is just bob.